# Overflow datastructure

Tags: overflow

Everyone knows about overflow in the programming languages, if it happens program goes to crash. However, it is not clear for me what happens actually with data which get out of the boundary. Could you explain me, saying, giving example on C++ or Java. For example, Integer can save maximum 4 byte, what will happen if one puts data more than 4 byte to Integer. How compiler will identify this undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what will happen if one puts data more than 4 byte to Integer.

*Typically* the value will *roll-over*<sup>1</sup>, meaning it will jump from one end of its range to another.

This can be seen, even in Windows calculator. Start with the highest possible *signed* 32-bit value:

[image]

Now add one to it:

[image]

We *overflowed* the maximum value of a signed Dword (2<sup>31</sup>-1).

<sup>1 - This is a typical result. Some architectures might actually generate an exception on integer overflow, so you shouldn't count on this behavior.</sup>

---

> How compiler will identify this undefined behaviour?

The compiler *won't* identify it. That's the problem. C# can mitigate this with the [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword, which checks to make sure that any arithmetic done on an integer will not cause overflow/underflow.